# In IOS mail app, How to Display mail attachments after mail body?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I am developing a Mail app in iOS.

When displaying an email's details / contents I cannot figure out how to display mail body and attachments together.

I searched for some mail apps in iPhone, like original Mail app and Sparrow which do this in almost the same way. The detail mail view is a UITableview, the sender and receiver is one UItableviewcell, the subject is one UItableviewcell, and the mail body and attachments are one UItableviewcell. Since the mail body may have html contents, I think it need use UIWebview to display, and the attachments are a new UITableView with rows being the number of attachments.

My question is:

How to put a UIwebview and a UItableView in one UITableViewCell?

I have tried to alloc a tableviewcell and add a webview and a tableview to the cell, but it don't work good.

Can anyone tell me what is the better way to implement this requirement? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you use the same tableview for all cells instead of creating a table in a table =)

in

```
-cellforrowat...{
}
```

you could make clauses

```
indexPath.row

0: subject
1: receiver,sender
2: webview for content
3: first attachement
4: second attachement
5: ... further attachements
```

so you could declare different `UITableViewCell` subclasses for

```
subject
adresses
webviewcell
attachment
```

and you know that for every `row > 2` (or so) you have to return an attachementcell

just an idea an probably my first idea to solve it

Comment: it is easy to do as you say.but i tried some mail app, they all let content and attachments in one tableviewcell. perhaps they use bottons after the webview. i think i can do in this way.

Comment: btw: welcome to stackoverflow ;-) dont forget to upcote &or accept abswers if you like them and they helped you :-)